# Knockout "with" binding, cascading dropdown, reload selected values not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, drop-down-menu, cascading

I have a knockout example, using "With" binding to create a cascading drop-down.

The Drop-down works fine, if i select the values, 4 drop-downs cascading with each corresponding select options.

However I would like to save the drop-down setup, so at a page load, i could get back the saved values, just like presetting the values.

Logging out the values the observables get by calling 'save', after selecting from drop-down. But doesn't work when calling 'loadPresetData', to simulate the data mapping into the observable selected values.

I have forked the fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/turrytheman/3urLenmd/

```
var sampleModel=[{"products":[{"name":"1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster","year":[{"name":2015,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"april"},{"name":"dec"}]}]},{"name":"1948 Porsche Type 356 Roadster","year":[{"name":2014,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"april"},{"name":"dec"}]},{"name":2015,"months":[{"name":"oct"},{"name":"marc"},{"name":"feb"}]}]},{"name":"1949 Jaguar XK 120","year":[{"name":2019,"months":[{"name":"oct"},{"name":"jun"},{"name":"jul"}]},{"name":2013,"months":[{"name":"oct"},{"name":"marc"},{"name":"feb"}]}]}],"name":"Classic Cars"},{"products":[{"name":"1936 Harley Davidson El Knucklehead","year":[{"name":2011,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"nov"},{"name":"sep"}]}]},{"name":"1957 Vespa GS150","year":[{"name":2014,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"april"},{"name":"dec"}]},{"name":2015,"months":[{"name":"another"},{"name":"yet"},{"name":"another"}]}]}],"name":"Motorcycles"}];


var Cascading = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.category = ko.observable();
    self.product = ko.observable();
    self.years = ko.observable();
    self.month = ko.observable();

    // Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
    self.category.subscribe(function(val) {
       self.product(undefined);
    });
    self.product.subscribe(function(val) {
       self.years(undefined);
    });
    self.years.subscribe(function(val) {
       self.month(undefined);
    });

    // Operations
    self.loadPresetData = function() { //simulating a load, recieved from AJAX, setting saved values
        self.category(JSON.parse('{"products":[{"name":"1936 Harley Davidson El Knucklehead","year":[{"name":2011,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"nov"},{"name":"sep"}]}]},{"name":"1957 Vespa GS150","year":[{"name":2014,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"april"},{"name":"dec"}]},{"name":2015,"months":[{"name":"another"},{"name":"yet"},{"name":"another"}]}]}],"name":"Motorcycles"}'));
        self.product(JSON.parse('{"name":"1936 Harley Davidson El Knucklehead","year":[{"name":2011,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"nov"},{"name":"sep"}]}]}'));
        self.years(JSON.parse('{"name":2015,"months":[{"name":"jan"},{"name":"april"},{"name":"dec"}]}'));
        self.month(JSON.parse('{"name":"april"}'));
}
    self.save = function() {
        var data = {"category": ko.toJSON(ko.toJS(self.category)),
                    "product": ko.toJSON(ko.toJS(self.product)),
                    "years": ko.toJSON(ko.toJS(self.years)) ,
                    "month": ko.toJSON(ko.toJS(self.month)) 
                    }
        console.log(data);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new Cascading());
```

HTML:

```
<div class='liveExample'> 
   <div>
       <select data-bind='options: sampleModel, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: category'> </select>
   </div>
   <div data-bind="with: category">
       <select data-bind='options: products, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.product'> </select>
   </div>
      <div data-bind="with: product">
       <select data-bind='options: year, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.years'> </select>
   </div>
      <div data-bind="with: years">
       <select data-bind='options: months, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.month'> </select>
   </div>
   <button data-bind='click: loadPresetData'>Load</button>
   <button data-bind='click: save'>Save</button>

    <div style="color: red"data-bind="text:'Category :' + ko.toJSON(category)"></div>
    <div style="color: green"data-bind="text:'Product :' + ko.toJSON(product)"></div>
    <div style="color: blue"data-bind="text:'Year :' + ko.toJSON(years)"></div>
    <div style="color: black"data-bind="text:'Months :' + ko.toJSON(month)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The dropdowns are not getting set because the `object` you are setting to `self.category()` and other dropdowns in `loadPresetData` don't exist in `sampleModel` (or `sampleProductCategories` in the fiddle).

Yes, there is an object that *looks* like and has the same properties and nested arrays as the object `JSON.parse()` creates, but they are totally **different** objects. They would fail a [`Strict Equality Comparison or "=== comparison"`](http://ttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). You can prove this hypothesis by setting the `category` and other cascading values from the `sampleProductCategories` array itself.

```
self.loadPresetData = function() {
   self.category(sampleProductCategories[1]);
   self.product(sampleProductCategories[1].products[0]);
   self.years(sampleProductCategories[1].products[0].year[0]);
   self.month(sampleProductCategories[1].products[0].year[0].months[0]);
};
```

Now, when `category` is updated, knockout goes and looks for this object in `sampleProductCategories`. It exists and hence `category` won't be set to `undefined`.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/jdntbmwc/)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i wanted. I should have think of this approach, but got stuck thinking one way... Great answer, short and concise.